# Google Docs appscript manipulating checkboxes or dropdown list

Tags: google-docs

I am currently working on a Google Apps Script project involving a Google Docs document. My objective is to interact with checkboxes or dropdown lists (Smart Chips) within the document.

Specifically, I need to read the state of checkboxes (checked or unchecked) and the selected values in dropdown lists to perform subsequent actions like keeping or removing certain sections of the document.

However, I've encountered challenges as it appears that the Google Apps Script API does not directly support these functionalities. The checkboxes are identified as UnsupportedElement, and extracting the selected values from dropdown lists is also proving difficult.

Iterating through the document to read the state of checkboxes and dropdown lists, but they are either identified as unsupported elements or do not return the expected values.
Considering alternative methods like text markers, but this approach compromises the desired user experience.
I am seeking suggestions or workarounds to overcome these limitations.

Thanks !

I tried to get the state of checkboxes
I tried to get the value of dropdown list

Here what I have
[a sample with checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fKzF.png)
or with dropdown
[a sample with dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeDzK.png)

[And what I need at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9SZ7.png)

Here is the code I have for the moment :

```
// Définissez DEBUG sur true pour activer les logs de débogage, sur false pour les désactiver
var DEBUG = true;

function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Actions Personnalisées')
      .addItem('Mettre à jour le document', 'processTableChoices')
      .addToUi();
}


function processTableChoices() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();

  if (DEBUG) {
    Logger.log('Début du traitement des tableaux...');
    Logger.log('Nombre total de tableaux: ' + tables.length);
  }

  tables.forEach(function(table, tableIndex) {
    if (DEBUG) {
      Logger.log('Traitement du tableau n° ' + (tableIndex + 1));
    }

    var numRows = table.getNumRows();

    for (var i = numRows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var row = table.getRow(i);
      var cell = row.getCell(0);
      var dropdownText = getDropdownValue(cell);

      if (DEBUG) {
        Logger.log('Traitement de la ligne ' + (i + 1) + ': Valeur : ' + dropdownText);
      }

      if (dropdownText === 'Conserver') {
        // Copie le contenu complexe de la cellule
        copyCellContent(body, row, i);
        table.removeRow(i);
      } else if (dropdownText === 'Supprimer') {
        if (DEBUG) {
          Logger.log('Suppression de la ligne ' + (i + 1));
        }
        table.removeRow(i);
      }
    }

    if (table.getNumRows() === 0) {
      if (DEBUG) {
        Logger.log('Suppression du tableau n° ' + (tableIndex + 1));
      }
      table.removeFromParent();
    }
  });
}

function copyCellContent(body, row, rowIndex) {
  var numCells = row.getNumCells();
  for (var j = 1; j < numCells; j++) {
    var cell = row.getCell(j);
    var numChildren = cell.getNumChildren();
    for (var k = 0; k < numChildren; k++) {
      var child = cell.getChild(k);
      if (child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
        // Copie le tableau entier
        var table = child.asTable();
        var copiedTable = body.insertTable(body.getChildIndex(row.getParentTable()), table.copy());
        body.insertParagraph(body.getChildIndex(copiedTable) + 1, ''); // Insère un paragraphe vide après le tableau pour la séparation
      } else if (child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        // Copie un paragraphe
        body.insertParagraph(body.getChildIndex(row.getParentTable()), child.asParagraph().copy());
      }
      // Ajouter ici des cas pour d'autres types d'éléments si nécessaire
    }
  }
}


function getDropdownValue(cell) {
  if (DEBUG) {
    Logger.log('Traitement de la cellule...');
  }

  try {
    var numChildren = cell.getNumChildren();
    if (DEBUG) {
      Logger.log('Nombre d\'enfants dans la cellule: ' + numChildren);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
      var child = cell.getChild(i);
      if (child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        var listItem = child.asListItem();
        var glyphType = listItem.getGlyphType();

        if (DEBUG) {
          Logger.log('Type de glyph trouvé: ' + glyphType);
        }

        // Vérifiez si le type de glyph correspond à une puce
        if (glyphType === DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET || glyphType === DocumentApp.GlyphType.HOLLOW_BULLET || glyphType === DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET) {
          return 'Conserver'; // ou toute autre valeur que vous associez à une puce
        }
      }
    }

    // Aucune puce trouvée, considérez que la ligne doit être supprimée
    return 'Supprimer';
  } catch (e) {
    if (DEBUG) {
      Logger.log('Erreur lors de la vérification des puces: ' + e.toString());
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `Here what I have enter image description here or with dropdown enter image description here` and `And what I need at the end enter image description here`, unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for achieving your expected result. Can you provide your current script? Also, can I ask you about the details of your current issue of your script and your logic for achieving your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi, I have a document model, and users need to choose one bloc of sentences. Each bloc can contain array, texte, images, etc. This is why I put everything in an array to manipulaire easily content. The only piece that I miss, is the user choice. I imagin doing this with checkboxes or dropdown list with 2 values to have an easy user experience.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to answer :) my english is not really good too. I try to have a dynamic document in docs. User can choose what paragraph he wants to have in the final document